# Validate choice list in Symfony2

Tags: php, validation, symfony-2.5, choicefield

I have a choice list where user can choose one value, but there I even set an empty value if the user doesn't select anything.

The form does not have model, to use @Assert annotation with it, and the choice field is optional, so in some case it will be hidden and need to be validated only if showed to user.

How I can validate this field? When I set it to required in my form type it didn't help (If I am right required equal to true by defaut). Where is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `NotBlank` validator to your field.

You can add a validator directly to your field, like this:

```
$this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('exampleField', 'choice', array(
            'label' => 'Label',
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(),
            ),
        ))
[...]
```

Comment: hm, It search form, and it without model. I think I need to add more details to my post.

Comment: No model required, you can add a validator directly to your form field.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: You're wrong, @RiggsFolly, this is the correct answer. I will expand with a code example.